# Offset page to prevent sticky header from covering auto-generated anchors

Tags: html, anchor, markdown, jekyll

I'm using jekyll to generate my pages and as anyone knows that uses jekyll, the anchor tags on h-tags are automatically generated.

### Solutions I am not looking for:

1. **Add padding** — my h-tags are using margins because I'm a normal person. Also, my sticky header is 50px tall which means that all my h-tags would need a miniumum of 55(ish)px padding. This causes there to be too much spacing.
2. **Create your own anchor in a `span` tag** — this defeats the point of the autogenerated tags and I'm trying to live a D.R.Y. lifestyle.

**Summary**: I need to offset the anchor's position without changing the location of the h-tag.

---

If this has already been answered, I apologize for creating a duplicate question. I could not find the answer to this that was not 'solved' with the previous mentioned 'solutions'.

Comment: I didn't understand your question, would you please add some code showing what you have and how you want it?

Comment: I'm happy to provide more detail but I'm not quite sure what details I'm missing. I can provide some code but that won't help. The sticky header is covering the h-tag (that contains the anchor). I need to offset the anchor without changing the position of the h-tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use the `:target` pseudo selector, which matches when the hash in the URL and the id of an element are the same. Therefore, the style will only apply to the h-tag which has been navigated to rather than all of them.

For example, you can use `:target::before` to add a margin to the top of the selected tag:

```
:target::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      margin-top: -75px;
      height: 75px;
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/pull/846/files), this technique was used along with an animation which removes the margin after one second so that the margin no longer exists if/when the user scrolls up the page.

Comment: That worked! For anyone who might be interested, I was able to get the desired effect just with the `:before` pseudo selector. For example: `h1:before, h2:before, h3:before, h4:before {content:"";display:block;margin-top:-75px;height:75px;}`

Answer (score 1):

Adding this solved my problem.

```
html {
  scroll-padding-top: 70px; /* height of sticky header */
}
```